# Adding youtube video to my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, youtube-api

This is how i added a youtube video to my project; I have added these to the viewDidLoad Function

```
UIWebView *web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 300)]; 
NSString *html = @"<html><head> .........."; // its too long so i cut it short
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/vLBKOcUbHR0"]];

    [self.view addSubview:web];
```

The view what i see is;

[image]

And what i want is some thing like this

[image]

If you look closer, you will see a ToolBar and a DOne button, and also a UIActivityIndicator in the second image, and  none of these are displaying in mine. How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not really how you use baseURL. The Base URL is what relative links will be relative to if there are links in the HTML - mapping it to youtube probably won't help at all.

Instead, just copy the embed code from youtube, which looks like this:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2WNrx2jq184" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Copy the URL from the iframe and open it directly in your web view, like this:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/2WNrx2jq184"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

That should work.

Comment: Is there a way to auto play the video without showing the start screen (like a thumbnail view, where you have to click on the play button) ?

Comment: Not that I know of. You might be able to do something hacky like use the webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method to execute a script on the embedded player to make it play, but that sounds quite fragile if YouTube ever change their API.